# Why won't this C++ program compile and run?

Tags: c++, terminal

I tried to run a basic C++ file in the terminal:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cont << "This is my first C++ program!";
    return 0
}
```

And then tried to run it in the terminal:

```
make learningCPP.cpp

    make: *** No rule to make target `learningCPP.cpp'.  Stop.
```

And tried:

```
make learningCPP

    make: *** No rule to make target `learningCPP'.  Stop.
```

And tried:

```
gcc learningCPP.cpp -o learningCPP.out

    clang: error: no such file or directory: 'learningCPP.cpp'
    clang: error: no input files
```

Here is the entire Bash/Clang file:

```
Last login: Mon May 25 07:49:21 on console

make learningCPP.cpp

    make: *** No rule to make target `learningCPP.cpp'.  Stop.

make learningCPP

    make: *** No rule to make target `learningCPP'.  Stop.

gcc learningCPP.cpp -o learningCPP.out

    clang: error: no such file or directory: 'learningCPP.cpp'
    clang: error: no input files

$ g++ -o lab21 learningCPP.cpp

    -bash: $: command not found

$ ./lab21

    -bash: $: command not found

./learningCPP.cpp

    -bash: ./learningCPP.cpp: No such file or directory

./main

    -bash: ./main: No such file or directory

$ g++ -o main learningCPP.cpp

    -bash: $: command not found

cpp

make learningCPP.cpp

run
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: `clang: error: no such file or directory: 'learningCPP.cpp'` -- Was your file called `learningCPP.cpp`? And was it in the current directory? It sounds like `g++` isn't installed on this machine. What does `g++ -v` output?

Comment: Type in `ls` and press Enter. Is `learningCpp.cpp` one of the files listed?

Comment: The input shows no attempts to execute g++.  There's always a bogus `$` before it.

Comment: You don't "run" cpp files, you compile them. It appears you weren't paying attention during a really important part of your class.

Comment: _`cont << ... `_ You're sure about this line of code?

Comment: Yes I'm sure about the code. And I'm teaching myself. I'm not out of middle school yet. The output of g++ -v was: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0
Thread model: posix. The program was put in a folder called C++ in a folder called Coding. ls returned the Coding folder and I couldn't get further. That was amouthful

Comment: I am voting to ***delete this question*** because it has very little value without more information from the OP about the current directory and its contents. And the OP is probably never coming back - *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the errors, your file either isn't called `learningCPP.cpp`, or isn't in the directory you're trying to compile it from.

Rename it so it has that name, or change directory to its location, then the build command is

```
g++ learningCPP.cpp -o learningCPP
```

not `gcc`, and with no spurious `$` before it. Alternatively, as long as the source file is present in the working directory, you could use `make learningCPP`.

Once that succeeds, run the program with

```
./learningCPP
```

although you'll have to read the new error messages, and use that to figure out how to fix the syntax errors, before it will compile.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work.

Comment: @KawikaDembroski: What didn't work? Is the file definitely called `learningCPP.cpp`? And definitely in the current directory? And did you definitely use exactly the command I suggested? If so, what was the error message?

Comment: I did it over and over again, and the command was: clang: error: no such file or directory: 'learningCPP.cpp'
clang: error: no input files

Comment: On that happy note, I have figured out that it doesn't run java or python with the same or similar error.